# Acessing to global variable from class function in Python

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I want to get a variable which can be used at any method from any class.

I started like this:

```
class clasificadorDeTweet:

    """Funciones para clasificar tweets"""
    def fx():
        print trendingTopics

def iniciarConjuntoTrendingTopics():

    trendingTopics = ['EPN', 'PRI', 'Peña Nieto', 'México', 'PresidenciaMX', 'Osorio Chong', 'SEDENA', 'PEMEX', 'Reforma Energética', 'Guerra contra el narco', 'Reforma Fiscal', 'Los Pinos'];
    return set(trendingTopics)

global trendingTopics 
trendingTopics = iniciarConjuntoTrendingTopics()

x=clasificadorDeTweet()
x.fx
```

But I'm not getting anything printed. What have I got wrong?

Comment: `x.fx` is not a function call; you're not executing your `fx` function

Comment: You did not **call** the method: `x.fx()`.

Comment: You should define `fx` as `def fx(self):`. Methods require an explicit self parameter to indicate the instance.

Comment: You quite got it @Bakuriu. You should prompt and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **call** the method `x.fx` by adding `()` after it:

```
x.fx()
```

However, this isn't your only problem; `fx` is an instance method, so it needs to take `self` (by convention; you can call it anything you want, but you need to have some parameter) as the first parameter.

You probably also want to use unicode strings in `trendingTopics` and declare a source encoding at the start of your file; embedding non-ASCII `str`s in your code may coincidentally work perfectly fine, then break horribly when moved to another system.

Your `global` statement at the module level also does literally nothing at all. Variables assigned at the module scope are already globals.

Comment: When should I use global then? When I perform assignments to such variable names?

Comment: `global` lets you rebind the name globally from within some other scope. But you "should" use it pretty much never; using globals is generally a bad practice because it makes it harder to reason about code.

Comment: I got 

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

As begin of my code, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want acces to trendingTopics, you have to declare trendingTopics as global on the method scope

def fx():
      global tredingTopics
      print tredingTopics